# Add DLL to program from code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dll

Here's my problem.

I want to create an installable with DLLs. When I use it on the PC I developed the code it works just fine, but when I try to install it on another PC it doesn't add the DLLs. I think I need to add them from the source code or something like that, but I can't do it.

I was wondering if there's someone that could point me to some reading material as to how I can do it.

Comment: Is this a winform application? Do you use a installer project to create the installer?

Comment: How do you reference your dlls in your project? If you're going straight to GAC the installer won't copy the files itself.

Comment: Yes it's a WinForm application. The installer I use is the one that comes with Visual Studio 2010 (I'm programming in C#). In my code I simlpy add them using the "using" term. Is there another way I can reference these DLLs? If maybe I create an installable that adds them in a specific folder within the installable then maybe I could reference them in the code, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Using "using" you reference namespaces, not dlls. Please take a look at the "References" folder in Solution Explorer and try to find our where those dlls actually come from.

Comment: I'll try that. The probem is that I'm a newbie and I'm learning thing the second I need them, so there are many things that I didn't learn on the way

Comment: OK, I checked it. I created the DLLs and a reference to them is made in the "Reference" folder in Solution Explorer. The reference is made to the folder they're in. There isn't more I could say about that, I think.

Comment: Sure thing, we've all been there :) Could you check if the dlls are being copied to your bin folder (Debug, release or whatever you use) when you build your application?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7686/discussion-between-morcillo-and-piotr-justyna)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that the dlls used by the project were not the part of the solution. To fix this **morcillo** had to:

- remove existing references to those dlls
- add those dlls to the solution manually
- reference the dlls from the solution

Glad I could help.
Piotr